# Book in "Where's Waldo" style with 2 kids, 3 book-ish character and characters from other stories

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a picture book with a *Where's Waldo* style I was reading when I was a child in early 2000s.

You had to find the "main characters" of the book: a boy, a girl and 3 anthropomorphic books: a blue one, a pink one and a rather grotesque green one.

You also had to find the word "EXIT" somewhere on the double page in order to go to the next double page.

The double pages were also filled with plenty of characters from other popular stories and each double pages had a theme like horror (ft. the Frankenstein monster, the Phantom of the Opera, Dr. Jekyll/Mr. Hyde, ...), pirates (Robinson Crusoe, the Treasure Island, ...)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, it's fine to keep the mistakes in and probably would help other people searching with the incorrect memories too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [*The Pagemaster: Who's in the Library With Richard?*](https://archive.org/details/pagemaster00dave/page/n3) (1994)

> The reader must help Richard find his way through the Kingdom of Books by identifying six characters, the stories they come from, and the exit in the illustrations

> A colorful and detailed "look for" book follows the tradition of Where's Waldo? by compelling young readers to search for Richard, Adventure, Fantasy, Horror, and a host of fairy-tale characters in a variety of busy scenes based on literary classics
>
> <sub>[Amazon, *The Pagemaster: Who's in the Library With Richard?*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1570360316)</sub>

[image: The book's front cover]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

Found with the Google query `"seek and find" book find the exit` which led me to the Amazon entry linked above.

Comment: Yes, that's it ! Thank you very much !